# NullPointerException Error in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I am trying this code (in Netbeans) and i always get a long list of errors (here only the first rows)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FootballFrame.jComboBox1ActionPerformed(FootballFrame.java:64
at FootballFrame.access$000(FootballFrame.java:3)
at FootballFrame$1.actionPerformed(FootballFrame.java:29)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1260)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:588)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:624)
at Javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:835)
```

...

The code is as follows :

```
  private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
  {                                          
      String support = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
      league.setLeagueName(support);
  }
```

the method league.setLeagueName(String aName) works perfectly outside ... and i really don't understand

Comment: Try using the debugger, I can only assume that `getSelectedItem()` returns null.

Comment: perfectly outside where?

Comment: maybe jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() would work?

Comment: Which line is line 64? Also, can you post the code for `setLeagueName`?

Comment: I made a Test Class and it works

Comment: @Ali: the exception was an NPE, not a `ClassCastException`; `toString()` is actually *more* likely to throw an NPE than a cast (because `(String) null` is valid but `null.toString()` isn't)

Comment: toString does not change

Comment: Could you post the code for `setLeagueName` please?

Comment: public void setLeague(String aName){ name = aName }

Comment: league is null, you could be shadowing the variable which is why it "works perfectly outside", but you've not posted enough information for the question to be properly answered. And you need to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Components need to be initialised before use with `initComponents()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` means that you're trying to do something to a `null` object. In the code above, there are three things that could be causing the problem:

- `jComboBox1` could be `null`
- the result of `jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()` could be `null` (though this might not cause an error; it could just set the value to `null` and fail later)
- `league` could be `null`

So, to find out which, you could either use the debugger, or change the code to the following:

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                       
    System.out.println("jComboBox1 : " + jComboBox1);                   
    String support = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("support : " + support);
    System.out.println("league : " + league);
    league.setLeagueName(support);
}
```

See which print statement (or statements) prints `null`, and then go from there to figure our how to remedy the problem.

If you choose to use the debugger (which you should probably learn how to do), you could keep the original code, and then add a breakpoint at the first line of the method. Then, run your app in debug mode and take a look at the variables. Step through the code and see what is `null` and why.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, this could not be the second point.